# Node.js + Socket.IO scaling with redis + cluster

Tags: node.js, nginx, amazon-ec2, socket.io, load-balancing

Currently, I'm faced with the task where I must scale a Node.js app using Amazon EC2. From what I understand, the way to do this is to have each child server use all available processes using cluster, and have sticky connections to ensure that every user connecting to the server is "remembered" as to what worker they're data is currently on from previous sessions.

After doing this, the next best move from what I know is to deploy as many servers as needed, and use nginx to load balance between all of them, again using sticky connections to know which "child" server that each users data is on.

So when a user connects to the server, is this what happens?

Client connection -> Find/Choose server -> Find/Choose process -> Socket.IO handshake/connection etc.

If not, please allow me to better understand this load balancing task. I also do not understand the importance of redis in this situation.

Below is the code I'm using to use all CPU's on one machine for a seperate Node.js process:

```
var express = require('express');
cluster = require('cluster'),
net = require('net'),
sio = require('socket.io'),
sio_redis = require('socket.io-redis');

var port = 3502,
num_processes = require('os').cpus().length;

if (cluster.isMaster) {
// This stores our workers. We need to keep them to be able to reference
// them based on source IP address. It's also useful for auto-restart,
// for example.
var workers = [];

// Helper function for spawning worker at index 'i'.
var spawn = function(i) {
    workers[i] = cluster.fork();

    // Optional: Restart worker on exit
    workers[i].on('exit', function(worker, code, signal) {
        console.log('respawning worker', i);
        spawn(i);
    });
};

// Spawn workers.
for (var i = 0; i < num_processes; i++) {
    spawn(i);
}

// Helper function for getting a worker index based on IP address.
// This is a hot path so it should be really fast. The way it works
// is by converting the IP address to a number by removing the dots,
// then compressing it to the number of slots we have.
//
// Compared against "real" hashing (from the sticky-session code) and
// "real" IP number conversion, this function is on par in terms of
// worker index distribution only much faster.
var worker_index = function(ip, len) {
    var s = '';
    for (var i = 0, _len = ip.length; i < _len; i++) {
        if (ip[i] !== '.') {
            s += ip[i];
        }
    }

    return Number(s) % len;
};

// Create the outside facing server listening on our port.
var server = net.createServer({ pauseOnConnect: true }, function(connection) {
    // We received a connection and need to pass it to the appropriate
    // worker. Get the worker for this connection's source IP and pass
    // it the connection.
    var worker = workers[worker_index(connection.remoteAddress, num_processes)];
    worker.send('sticky-session:connection', connection);
}).listen(port);
} else {
// Note we don't use a port here because the master listens on it for us.
var app = new express();

// Here you might use middleware, attach routes, etc.

// Don't expose our internal server to the outside.
var server = app.listen(0, 'localhost'),
    io = sio(server);

// Tell Socket.IO to use the redis adapter. By default, the redis
// server is assumed to be on localhost:6379. You don't have to
// specify them explicitly unless you want to change them.
io.adapter(sio_redis({ host: 'localhost', port: 6379 }));

// Here you might use Socket.IO middleware for authorization etc.

console.log("Listening");
// Listen to messages sent from the master. Ignore everything else.
process.on('message', function(message, connection) {
    if (message !== 'sticky-session:connection') {
        return;
    }

    // Emulate a connection event on the server by emitting the
    // event with the connection the master sent us.
    server.emit('connection', connection);

    connection.resume();
});
}
```

Answer (score 34):

I believe your general understanding is correct, although I'd like to make a few comments:

### Load balancing

You're correct that one way to do load balancing is having nginx load balance between the different instances, and inside each instance have cluster balance between the worker processes it creates. However, that's just one way, and not necessarily always the best one.

#### Between instances

For one, if you're using AWS anyway, you might want to consider using [ELB](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/). It was designed specifically for load balancing EC2 instances, and it makes the problem of configuring load balancing between instances trivial. It also provides a lot of useful features, and (with [Auto Scaling](https://aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/)) can make scaling extremely dynamic without requiring any effort on your part.

One feature ELB has, which is particularly pertinent to your question, is that it supports sticky sessions [out of the box](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/elb-sticky-sessions.html) - just a matter of marking a checkbox.

However, I have to add a major caveat, which is that ELB can break socket.io in [bizarre ways](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/1846). If you just use long polling you should be fine (assuming sticky sessions are enabled), but getting actual websockets working is somewhere between extremely frustrating and impossible.

#### Between processes

While there are a lot of alternatives to using cluster, both [within](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28599586/nodejs-on-multiple-processors-pm2-cluster-recluster-naught) Node and [without](http://blog.keithcirkel.co.uk/load-balancing-node-js/), I tend to agree cluster itself is usually perfectly fine.

However, one case where it does *not* work is when you want sticky sessions behind a load balancer, as you apparently do here.

First off, it should be made explicit that the only reason you even need sticky sessions in the first place is because socket.io relies on session data stored in-memory between requests to work (during the handshake for websockets, or basically throughout for long polling). In general, relying on data stored this way should be avoided as much as possible, for a variety of reasons, but with socket.io you don't really have a choice.

Now, this doesn't seem too bad, since cluster *can* support sticky sessions, using the [sticky-session](https://github.com/indutny/sticky-session) module mentioned in socket.io's [documentation](http://socket.io/docs/using-multiple-nodes/), or the [snippet](https://github.com/elad/node-cluster-socket.io) you seem to be using.

The thing is, since these sticky sessions are based on the client's IP, they won't work behind a load balancer, be it nginx, ELB, or anything else, since all that's visible inside the instance at that point is *the load balancer's* IP. The `remoteAddress` your code tries to hash isn't actually the client's address at all.

That is, when your Node code tries to act as a load balancer between *processes*, the IP it tries to use will just always be the IP of the other load balancer, that balances between *instances*. Therefore, all requests will end up at the same process, defeating cluster's whole purpose.

You can see the details of this issue, and a couple of potential ways to solve it (none of which particularly pretty), in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30706420/3412775).

### The importance of Redis

As I mentioned earlier, once you have multiple instances/processes receiving requests from your users, in-memory storage of session data is no longer sufficient. Sticky sessions are one way to go, although other, arguably better solutions exist, among them central session storage, which Redis can provide. See this [post](https://serversforhackers.com/so-you-got-yourself-a-loadbalancer) for a pretty comprehensive review of the subject.

Seeing as your question is about socket.io, though, I'll assume you probably meant Redis's specific importance for websockets, so:

When you have multiple socket.io servers (instances/processes), a given user will be connected to only one such server at any given time. However, any of the servers may, at any time, wish to emit a message to a given user, or even a broadcast to all users, regardless of which server they're currently under.

To that end, socket.io supports "Adapters", of which Redis is one, that allow the different socket.io servers to communicate among themselves. When one server emits a message, it goes into Redis, and then all servers see it (Pub/Sub) and can send it to their users, making sure the message will reach its target.

This, again, is explained in socket.io's [documentation](http://socket.io/docs/using-multiple-nodes/) regarding multiple nodes, and perhaps even better in this Stack Overflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18650183/3412775).

Comment: I learned so much from this answer that I have to express my gratitude, rules be damned.

Comment: One of the best answers ever